# codeigniter htaccess code issues with 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, redirect

we are using codeiniter index.php removal code in .htaccess, it works fine for us. but we have some redirects in .htacess and codeiniter code conflect with our redirect pages.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


Redirect 301 /articles/page-title.html http://domain.com/p/page-title.html
```

We redirected like this: "http://domain.com/p/page-title.html?/articles/page-title.html"

how we can fix and remove extra "?/articles/page-title.html" url from our redirect?

thaks

Comment: Try placing the redirect about your first `RewriteCond`

Comment: Sorry! how we can use RewriteCond for redirect?

Comment: No I mean place the following line - `Redirect 301 /articles/page-title.html http://domain.com/p/page-title.html` after the line - `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Have you tried removing the `?` from `index.php?/`

Comment: same redirect to: http://domain.com/p/page-title.html?/articles/page-title.html, if we can remove codeiniter code, it fixed, but whole codigniter broken.

Comment: Have you tried what @Pattle said?  Move your 301s near the top after the RewriteBase declaration.

Comment: how i can place RewriteCond ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this in your `.htaccess`.  Note that I've moved your redirect further up

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 /articles/page-title.html http://domain.com/p/page-title.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: yeah it redirect on redirect page but, include ?/articles/page-title.html in url

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar issue of it appending the old string at the end after a ? by using a RewriteRule with 301 rather than a Redirect. It's something to do with the rewrite rules always happening first. Putting the line in just after the RewriteBase so yours would look like this...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(/articles/page-title.html)$ /p/page-title.html [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```